# Pagination for custom wordpress plugin backend

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, pagination

I have a custom plugin which have lots of table. that's why i need a proper pagination.
Now i have a pagination but it show all 1 to 80 serially.
Here is that code for pagination.

```
<?php

echo '<div id="pager">Page : <div class="btn-group">';
while( $loopLimit != $loopStart )
{
    echo '<a class="btn" href="admin.php?page=wp-glossary&requireTab=viewDelEditWord&totalItems='.$totalItems.'&currentPage='.$loopStart.'&orderByWord='.$_REQUEST["orderByWord"].'"';
    if ($loopStart == $currentPage) {echo ' id="activeParer"';}
    echo '>'.$loopStart.'</a>';
    $loopStart ++ ;
}
echo '</div></div>';

?>
```

Here is present pegination view: [image]

I want 1 2 3 4....10 11 12 like this. how i change this.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code. and let me know if any.

```
    echo '<div id="pager">Page : <div class="btn-group">';
$loopStart = 1;
$currentPage = 4;
$loopLimit = 100;
$start_number_diplay = 5; // Number where you display in paganation in start and end.
$middle_number_diplay = 3;
$i = $j = 1; $total_pagination_display = 10;
while( $loopLimit != $loopStart )
{
    if( ($loopStart == ($start_number_diplay+1))  || ($total_pagination_display == $j)) {
        echo '<a class="btn" >...</a>';
        $j++;

    }

    echo '<a class="btn" href=""';
    if ($loopStart == $currentPage) {
        echo ' id="activeParer"';
    }
    if(($loopStart <= $start_number_diplay) ) {

        echo '>'.$loopStart.' </a>';
        $j++;

    }
    else if( (($loopStart%10) == 0) && ($i <= $middle_number_diplay) ) {
        echo '>'.$loopStart.' </a>';
        $i++;
        $j++;
    }
    $loopStart ++ ;

}
echo '</div></div>';
```

Comment: Thanks for Reply. it doesn't work properly. After add this code it look like this image: https://db.tt/HecxIV7B But i want stander pagination like this: https://db.tt/bgG0wVBg Please give me a best process. Thanks again.

Comment: @mrhossen Please check updated code, I made just only example code. Please change it with your suitable code.